# Deploying my website when all tests pass?

Tags: c#, tfs, build

I have a modified build template made from the default build template in Team Foundation Server 2013.

This is being built on a build server, and the solution being built contains both a web application project (MVC) and a console application which will run all the time.

I modified the template so that my build server deploys and runs the console application if all tests pass successfully.

Now, I want the build server to also make a deployment of my website, **but only if my tests pass**. All the examples of MSBuild or MSDeploy I could find will publish already when the project builds, and not after running the tests.

I don't know how to accomplish this. Is it possible? Where do I start?

Comment: Question is about, finding the spot in a modified Default template to add the check-and-deploy code, or how to check the Test result status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check the [BuildDetail.TestStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.server.builddetail.teststatus.aspx) property for a Succeeded value. This is the condition you have to set in an If activity (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968405/tfs-workflow-if-statement-using-build-configuration)) wrapping your deployment code.